# Understanding coverage when @TestSetup is used in a test class

Tags: community, test-setup

I have a `Test class` which include a method with @testSetup annottation. After saving this class it was added in list `Overall Code Coverage` like in the picture bottom. I was confused after that.

[image: Picture]
When I deleted the method `setup()` from my `Test class` the row `Test_ScheduleChangeMetadata - 0%` was hided from list `Overall Code Coverage`.

It is normally for this situation or it is an issue for Salesforce? How I should right cover this method?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your test data creation method utilized by any of the other methods in your test class?

Comment: No this method doesn't used by any other methods because this not needed. In documentation told that this method start automatically. [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_testsetup_using.htm)

Comment: I'm not asking about the `method`, I'm asking about the **data** it creates. If the data it creates isn't used, then the `method` isn't being used. In which case, it would presumably need a test class to validate it. Note also that `"If the test class or a test method has access to organization data by using the @isTest(SeeAllData=true) annotation, test setup methods aren’t supported in this class."` and `"If a test setup method calls a non-test method of another class, no code coverage is calculated for the non-test method."`

Comment: In dev console, classes marked with the test annotation show up but you can ignore the coverage as test classes are excluded from calculations. One of the many things that are irritating about the dev console.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not understood you at once. So Yes, I use these test `data` in another test method. Something like this. I select this data using the soql query and send they in methods of `ScheduleChangeMetadata` class. And I don't use `SeeAllData=true` in the test class.

Comment: Thank You @Eric. I think you are right. Just 0% of these lines bothered me.